# Dividing columns with an even group size, randomly in r

Tags: r, split, sample

I have a data.frame with 4000 rows and 600 columns. I should divide 600 columns into 10 groups, randomly with an even group size of 60. i tried to use **sample** or **split** but answer was not right. Please guide me.

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way is to do this is to first rearrange the column index and then split it in the 10 equal size. Assuming `df` is the data.frame following code should work

```
a <- sample(600)
b <- split(a, ceiling((1:600)/10))
result <- lapply(b, FUN = function(x) df[, x])
```